# SQL select top 3 or more if there are more items sharing the 3rd highest value?

Tags: mysql, sql

Any SQL experts out there who can explain how I select say the top 3 items.  When the 3rd item is equal to the 4th and 5th I'd like those included too but only in that situation.  e.g. with the following list

```
40,
30,
15,
15,
15,
10
```

it would return 40,30,15,15,15 not 40,30,15.

Comment: So, when the 2nd item is equal to the 3rd and 4th, but not the 5th?

Comment: To make sure I understand the question right: I.e., if your first 5 values are 40, the output then should be only 5 times 40 or 5 times 40 and the next 2 distinct values (both as often as they are present)?

Comment: Yes, essentially it's a scoring system where you want the top 3 players however if 3rd place is tied you want to also show anyone in tied 3rd place.

Comment: The requirement is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to output only the score field, you can do it like this:

```
SET @ranks = 3;

PREPARE stmt_top3 FROM
    'SELECT score FROM (
        SELECT score, (@row := @row + 1), IF (@row = ?, @min_score := score, NULL)
            FROM user_score
            WHERE score IN (
                SELECT top_score.score FROM (
                    SELECT DISTINCT score,
                    (@row := 0), (@min_score := 0)
                        FROM user_score
                        ORDER BY score DESC
                        LIMIT ?
                ) AS top_score
            )
            ORDER BY score DESC
        ) AS score_rows
        WHERE score >= @min_score
        ORDER BY score DESC';

EXECUTE stmt_top3 USING @ranks, @ranks;
```

DEMO @ **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f23bf/1)**

I used a prepared statement, so the number of ranks to show is flexible. If you don't want that, just hardcode a `3` instead of the 2 `?`.

Otherwise, if you also need the rank and the user_id, i.e., here's a more extensive approach:

**Highscore-Like Ranking (Shared Ranks)**

*Selects all rows that share the first rank, no matter how many there are.
As long as the number of these rows is not greater than or equal to the maximum of ranks allowed (3 in your example) the next rank is the number of rows + 1.
And everything begins from the start and so on ...*

```
SET @ranks = 3;

PREPARE stmt_top3 FROM
    'SELECT user_score.user_id, score_rank.rank, score_rank.score
        FROM user_score
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT (@last_rank := @last_rank + @last_equal_score) AS rank,
                score, (@last_equal_score := count(score)) AS equal_score
                FROM user_score
                WHERE score IN (
                    SELECT top_score.score FROM (
                        SELECT DISTINCT score,
                        (@last_rank := 1), (@last_equal_score := 0)
                            FROM user_score
                            ORDER BY score DESC
                            LIMIT ?
                    ) AS top_score
                )
                GROUP BY score
                ORDER BY score DESC
        ) AS score_rank
        ON user_score.score = score_rank.score
        WHERE score_rank.rank <= ?
        ORDER BY score_rank.rank ASC';

EXECUTE stmt_top3 USING @ranks, @ranks;
```

DEMO @ [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09034/1)

Due to the fact that MySQL does not support `LIMIT` in subqueries for certain subquery operators such as `IN`, you have to wrap your subquery that contains a `LIMIT` clause in another simple subquery to avoid the following error:

> ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support  'LIMIT
>   & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

[**Restrictions on Subqueries**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-restrictions.html)

**I used the following setup for testing:**

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO user (id) VALUES
    (NULL),
    (NULL),
    (NULL),
    (NULL),
    (NULL),
    (NULL);

CREATE TABLE user_score (
    user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    score INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    INDEX (score),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO user_score (user_id, score) VALUES
    (1, 40),
    (2, 30),
    (3, 15),
    (4, 15),
    (5, 15),
    (6, 10);
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response however it's not quite right.  If I had a list of say 40,30,30,15,10 I only want the 40,30,30 values (as top 3).  It's only when the 3rd value is shared with 4th, 5th, etc.. does it produce a longer list.   Guess another way of saying it is "Find the top 3 values and return these rows.  If the 3rd value = 4th, 5th, 6th etc... value return these too".  What I'm trying to achieve is like a highscore table where it shows the top 3 scores but it will show more if others share this 3rd place score.

Comment: @sradforth - Ah ok, I understand. Highscore table is a good description. I'll give it another try in a free minute.

Comment: @sradforth - I updated my answer. Now, it's behaving like a classic highscore ranking system.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable
WHERE Field1 IN(
    SELECT * 
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT Field1 
        FROM myTable
        ORDER BY Field1 DESC
        LIMIT 3)
    ) t
```

The only issue you might have from your example is if you specifically DON'T want to include duplicates of 40 & 30?

Comment: This won't work due to MySQL's [**Restrictions on Subqueries**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-restrictions.html). A `LIMIT` clause can't be used in `IN` subqueries.

Comment: My bad, seems you need a wrapper query to force LIMIT to compile in this situation - answer edited, thanks!